# Writing a script

Tags: shell-script

I'm supposed to write a bash script that has as an argument a path to a directory which contains a file named *checking.txt*. It needs to return the following exit codes:

- 4, if the directory doesn't exist
- 5, if that directory is not a subdirectory of /home/user5/task05/
- 6, if *checking.txt* doesn't exist

How can I write these conditionals ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about homework.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a student task therefore I will not provide a solution, but some links that will help you to find it on your own.

- [Exit status](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html) to specify the right exit code.
- [man test](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/1/test/) to test your conditions.

And I wish you good luck in finding solution.